# React - State not updating function is not updating state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Goal** - Show and hide specific content in `ResponseDetail` component based on whatever `<li>` item is selected within `ResponseList` component. Additionally, option 4 has some further configurations where content will also need to update based on user selection from `ResponseDetail`

**Current problem** - The default value of the `submittedSev` variable does not update for the `detail` prop on the `ResponseDetail` component. Even though the data has changed within the `data` variable. However `responseData` prop on `ResponseList` component does update accordingly.

**Desired outcome** - For the `submittedSev` variable to update in the`ResponseDetail` component. Currently stuck on the default value of "High".

**Adiitional thoughts** - Is there a better way to show/hide content here?

**app.tsx**

```
const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const [submittedSev, setSubmittedSev] = useState('High');
    const data = [
        {
            title: 'First option',
            body: ``
        },
        {
            title: 'Second option',
            body: `${submittedSev}`,
            sevChange: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Third option',
            body: `${submittedSev}`,
            sevChange: true
        }
    ];
    
    // Trying to track what option has been selected with some state
    const [currentOption, setCurrentOption] = useState(data[0]);

    const submittedSevChangeHandler = (sev) => {
        setSubmittedSev(sev);
    };

    
    const selectOptionHandler = (index) => {
        setCurrentOption(data[index]);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <aside>
                <ResponseList
                    onSelectOption={selectOptionHandler}
                    responseData={data}
                />
            </aside>
            <main>
                <ResponseDetail
                    details={currentOption}
                    onChangeSubmittedSevHandler={submittedSevChangeHandler}
                />
            </main>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**ResponseList.tsx** - This component simply renders out the list of responses. `body` prop correctly renders updates

```
const ResponseList = (props) => {
    return (
        <ul className="response-list">
            {props.responseData.map((response, i) => (
                <Response
                    key={i}
                    index={i}
                    title={response.title}
                    body={response.body}
                    onSelectOption={props.onSelectOption}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};
```

**ResponseDetail.tsx** - `props.details.body` not updating based on selection options

```
const ResponseDetail = (props) => {

    const submittedSevUpdateChangeHandler = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        props.onChangeSubmittedSevHandler(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {props.details.sevChange && (
                <div className="priority-selection">
                    <select onChange={submittedSevUpdateChangeHandler}>
                        <option value="Low">Low</option>
                        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
            )}
            <div className="response-detail">
                <p>{props.details.body}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here where you're taking a copy of submittedSev and storing it in objects:

```
const data = [
        {
            title: 'First option',
            body: ``
        },
        {
            title: 'Second option',
            body: `${submittedSev}`,
            sevChange: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Third option',
            body: `${submittedSev}`,
            sevChange: true
        }
    ];
```

These objects are then stored in `currentOption` including that body value when selectOptionHandler runs. You would need to update `currentOption` when `submittedSev` changes in order for the body value to change.

A simple fix is to use an index instead:

```
const [currentOptionIndex, setCurrentOptionIndex] = React.useState(0);

const selectOptionHandler = (index) => {
   setCurrentOptionIndex(index);
};
```

And:

```
<ResponseDetail
    details={data[currentOptionIndex]}
     onChangeSubmittedSevHandler={submittedSevChangeHandler}
/>
```

This means it's then always using the newly created object (with the correct body value).

Comment: You're right. Not sure why I'm complicating things